# Approximations of BMO functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis, duality-theorems, hardy-spaces

I couldn't think of a good title. There was a small detail when I was trying to prove something about the norm of BMO functions. This small detail is not directly related to the problem itself, but here it is:

Fix $Q \in \mathbb{R}^n$ a cube, and consider the following two classes of functions:

$$
\mathcal{F} = \left\{ a(x) - m_Qa: \text{supp}(a) \subset Q, \lVert a \rVert_{L^2(Q)} \leq 1 \right\}
$$

$$
\mathcal{G} = \left\{ a(x) : \text{supp}(a) \subset Q, \int_{Q} a = 0,  \lVert a \rVert_{L^2(Q)} \leq 1 \right\}
$$

where $m_Q a = \vert Q \vert^{-1} \int_Q a(x) dx $

I want to show that， for any $h \in L^2(Q)$
$$
\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \  \left\vert \ \int_Q h(x) f(x) \  \right\vert = \sup_{g \in \mathcal{G}} \  \left\vert \ \int_Q h(x) g(x) \  \right\vert
$$

In other words can I say that $$
\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \ f(x)  = \sup_{g \in \mathcal{G}} g(x)$$

Comment: @CalvinKhor You are right that the previous question I posted did not make too much sense and is not what I really wanted to ask. I changed my question.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood a little. For the last sup question, what is $x$? A fixed point?

Comment: Please explain the acronym BMO.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes, but I feel that the last line is a slightly stronger statement. What really mattered is the integration with respect to $h(x)$ part.

Comment: @JeanMarie Bounded Mean Oscillation.